# Omniture api tracklinkUrl usage in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, adobe-analytics

I wanted to use tracklinkUrl api provided by Omniture as part of the ADMS library for iOS.

```
- (void)trackLinkURL:(NSString *)linkURL 
    withLinkType:(NSString *)linkType 
        linkName:(NSString *)linkName 
     contextData:(NSDictionary *)contextData 
       variables:(NSDictionary *)variables;
```

The above is the syntax for this api.

All variables which were supposed to be logged I bundled them into "variables", but wanted to know how to set channel name and events for this. is my below approach right one.

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
ADMS_Measurement *measurement = [ADMS_Measurement sharedInstance];
[variables setObject:@"myobject" forKey:@"mykey"];        
[measurement setEvents:@"event49"];
measurement.channel = @"mychannel";
[measurement tracklinkURL:@"my link" withLinkType: @"o" linkName: @"link name" contextData:nil variables:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer. If we need to set the channel or any other variables set them as usual, no need to use "variables" parameter.

tracklinkURl still takes care of it.

So in nutshell, when you wanted to use tracklinkURL no need to take any extra precautions and just pass nil to variables parameters.